# Facebook: Dragon Age Legends

Tags: dragon-age-legends

I started playing this for the DA2 unlocks, and have quite enjoyed it.

Does anyone know why the abilities on my party members randomly change?

Derant, for example, the mage, had 3 abilities in the last version and now only has 2. I noticed that the ranger rogue Antor has lost 2 abilities since the last update.

Is this just game balancing? Are there any update notes anywhere?

Ref: http://apps.facebook.com/dragonagelegends

Comment: Had a quick look an ended up here, http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/category/289/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the update notes here,
http://dragonagelegends.com/blog/2011/6/15/release-notes-0413669.html

However this doesn't cover why NPC's have lost abilities.